# Deliberately sending a 403 response

Tags: http, http-status-code-403

The website I work on temporarily bans users after suspicious behaviour is detected. Currently the user is bounced to a page that has minimal UI and a message telling them their access has been denied.

This page currently returns a response code of 200 and I'm about to change it to 403 as I believe this could help alert spam bots that they've been blocked.

So, in short, the page will remain exactly as is, the functionality will not change, only the response code will change from being 200 -> 403.

Is this advisable or am I potentially going to cause problems that I do not anticipate?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was but became slightly paranoid about potentially causing issues I hadn't foreseen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds reasonable to me, per the definition of 403:

```
10.4.4 403 Forbidden

   The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
   Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated.
   If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make
   public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the
   reason for the refusal in the entity.  If the server does not wish to
   make this information available to the client, the status code 404
   (Not Found) can be used instead.
```